# Is there any way to take some confidential data from this site?

Tags: php, html, sql, code-injection

On my and my friend site is form with login textbox. If login doesn't exist error appears
`"Error occurred. 151SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected"`.
If I enter invalid login + some sql (e.g `"iu7' or '1=1'--"`) it doesn't show any data, nor any error.
Is that form safe? Is it possible to enter valid login + sql to switch login to it's password in result? What do you think of it?

Answer (score 2):

You should always escape the input values by using `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['...'])` before submitting a query. This way, you should be safe with any string they put in.

I don't think people on SO are going to help you inject other sites, so that's all I'm gonna say for now.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on how you're building your SQL commands with the posted data. If you are simply building a string out of the values, then you are at risk of SQL injection attacks.

Take a look at this article:

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

It explains how to build prepared statements in PHP, which will protect against SQL injection.